# Range of matches in regex

Tags: regex

I know that in regex one can specify the desired number of matches via the curly braces as
    {min,max}

I was going through this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and coudn,t understand what is meant by {1,} or {0,} etc.

Comment: These are the same as `+` and `*`. Whoever wrote `[0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,}` had no idea what they were doing - it is much better as `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` (unless `MSIE 2.` is valid).

Comment: Actually, My pattern is ignoring sub versions, so make that `\d+(?:\.\d+)*`. Easy fix `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is infinity in regex

`{0,}` = `*` is mean `{0,infinity}`

`{1,}` = `+` is mean `{1,infinity}`

Answer (score 2):

it means no upper bound, but a lower bound. eg

See : http://regexr.com?31piu

`\d{3,}`

will match all the sequences of 1 where there are more than 3 continous 1s, be it
four 1s, or ten 1s

**1111**----**1111111111**----*11*--*1*----**11111111111111111111**--**111**

Same way,

{1,} would mean 1 or more instances i.e. a `+`  wildcard

{0,} would mean 0 or more instances i.e. a `*` wildcard

Answer (score 0):

{n,} where n >= 0 : "Repeats the previous item at least n times. Greedy, so as many items as possible will be matched before trying permutations with less matches of the preceding item, up to the point where the preceding item is matched only n times."

Refer to [this regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html/), there's a lot of handy examples in it: